# Pandas compare rows to row with similar partial multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem description**

I have a multi-index pandas dataframe with the column 'value' as on of the columns:

```
index               name    value
('cat1', 'subcat1') henk    6
('cat2', 'subcat1') klaas   7
('cat3', 'subcat1') jan     10
('cat1', 'subcat2') piet    7
('cat2', 'subcat2') joris   8
('cat3', 'subcat2') corneel 9
```

I want to select all rows r with index (index0,index1) where the following holds:

```
r['value'] > ref['value']
```

Where ref has the same first index as r , and 'subcat1' as second index:

```
r.index0 == ref.index0 AND ref.index1 == 'subcat1'
```

This would result in:

```
index               name    value
('cat1', 'subcat2') piet    7
('cat2', 'subcat2') joris   8
```

So in short, how can i compare the values of the rows based on it's own multi-level index.

**Code i have so far**

So far i got code for selecting values larger than a reference index, but only with a complete index

```
import pandas as pd

indices = [['cat1','cat2','cat3','cat1','cat2','cat3'],['subcat1','subcat1','subcat1','subcat2','subcat2','subcat2']]

df = pd.DataFrame([
        {'value' : 6,'name' : 'henk'},
        {'value' : 7,'name' : 'klaas'},
        {'value' : 10,'name' : 'jan'},
        {'value' : 7,'name' : 'piet'},
        {'value' : 8,'name' : 'joris'},
        {'value' : 9,'name' : 'corneel'},
         ],index=indices)


result = df[(df['value'] > df.loc[('cat1','subcat1')]['value'])]
```

**Missing in this code**

The values are compared to a fixed index row, instead of selecting the reference row based on part of it's own index

Comment: How does selecting subcat1 result in subcat2 results?

Comment: @noumenal For each row, it is compared to the row with the same first index (cat1 ..) and subcat1 as second index. So for the results, the first entry ('piet',7) is compared with ('henk',6), since that row has the same first index, and has second index 'subcat1'. Since 7 > 6 it means that ('piet',7) is selected. In the same manner, 'corneel' is compared to 'jan', but since 9 < 10, corneel is not selected. All values with subcat1 are compared to themselves, but since x > x is always false, none of these are selected

Comment: In that case I would maybe consider looping row by row, maybe using `iloc`, rather than selection. If I understand correctly you wish to compare rows with the indexes (r, r + 1)?

Comment: not sure if i understand what you mean with r,r+1. I want to compare each row to another row which has the same first index, and the second index set to a fixed value.